# No Column error when SQLite table creation in Android with Android Studio

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-studio

I'm trying to implement a sqlite database for my code to save basic variables. However, when running on the emulator, I get a no column error. Any insight would be appreciated.
The error:

```
(1) table reg_info has no column named user_pass
04-08 00:28:35.402    3133-3133/com.example.cowman897.sqlitedatabase E/SQLiteDatabase﹕ Error inserting user_pass=ghd user_ass=ggg user_name=sd
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table reg_info has no column named user_pass (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO reg_info(user_pass,user_ass,user_name) VALUES (?,?,?)
```

My code is as follows:

```
public class TableData {

    public TableData() {
    }

    public static abstract class TableInfo implements BaseColumns {
        public static final String USER_NAME = "user_name";
        public static final String USER_PASS = "user_pass";
        public static final String USER_ASS = "user_ass";
        public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "user_info";
        public static final String TABLE_NAME = "reg_info";
    }
}

public class DatabaseOperations extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final int database_version = 3;
    public String CREATE_QUERY = "create table " + TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_NAME + " (" + null + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + TableData.TableInfo.USER_NAME + " text not null, " + TableData.TableInfo.USER_PASS + " text not null, " + TableData.TableInfo.USER_ASS + " text not null);";

    public DatabaseOperations(Context context) {
        super(context, TableData.TableInfo.DATABASE_NAME, null, database_version);
        Log.d("Database operations", "Database Created");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sdb) {
        sdb.execSQL(CREATE_QUERY);
        Log.d("Database operations", "Table Created");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    }

    public void putInformation(DatabaseOperations dop, String name, String pass, String ass) {
        SQLiteDatabase SQ = dop.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(TableData.TableInfo.USER_NAME, name);
        cv.put(TableData.TableInfo.USER_PASS, pass);
        cv.put(TableData.TableInfo.USER_ASS, ass);
        long k = SQ.insert(TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
        Log.d("Database operations", "One raw inserted");
    }
}
```

and the activity is just

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    Button sub;
    String Class, Date, Assignment;
    EditText Class_Field, Date_Field, Assignment_Field;
    Context ctx = this;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        Class_Field = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        Date_Field = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        Assignment_Field = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);

        sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Class = Class_Field.getText().toString();
                Date = Date_Field.getText().toString();
                Assignment = Assignment_Field.getText().toString();
                DatabaseOperations DB = new DatabaseOperations(ctx);
                DB.putInformation(DB, Class, Date, Assignment);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Assignment Added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think your table is not created...

Comment: Have you add `user_pass` column later on in your table? It might be possible that once your database is created and then you change db then new db changes do not take place. For that you need to uninstall app and run again. @user2850572

Comment: what is that null thing in create statement?

Comment: What the hell is this? `"create table " + TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_NAME + " (" + null + " integer primary key autoincrement, "` ... **NULL**?!

Answer (score 0):

Update your table creation statement as follows and try,

```
private static final String CREATE_QUERY = "CREATE TABLE " + TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_NAME + " (" + 
                                                 TableData.TableInfo._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                                                 TableData.TableInfo.USER_NAME + " text not null, " + 
                                                 TableData.TableInfo.USER_PASS + " text not null, "+ 
                                                 TableData.TableInfo.USER_ASS + " text not null "+
                                                  " )";
```